# Get Url from given array

Tags: regex, get

```
{ "uploadUrl": "https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/11705162112362643904472027/photo/899853939832211842569886" }
```

From here I just want the url part . How can I get the Url

https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/11705162112362643904472027/photo/899853939832211842569886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to parse this string then you can use

`https?:\/\/[^"]+`

**Explanation**

`https?` Starting with *http* or *https*

`:\/\/` Followed by *://*

`[^"]+` Any character but a double-quote

Which language are you using ?

Using JavaScript, you would not use a regexp **but a JSON parser** :

```js
var str = '{ "uploadUrl": "https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/11705162112362643904472027/photo/899853939832211842569886" }';

var url = JSON.parse(str).uploadUrl;

console.log(url);
```

Or, **using regex**

```js
var str = '{ "uploadUrl": "https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/media/user/11705162112362643904472027/photo/899853939832211842569886" }';

var re = /https?:\/\/[^"]*/;
var url = str.match(re)[0];

console.log(url);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nVcqH5/1)